# Avoid previous value from random selection from list

Tags: python, random

What I want my code to do is to print out 5 `wrong()` funcs without there being 2 in a row of the same text. And of course I don't want it to be by luck.

I want to make sure if I use this function at least twice I am 100% sure the previous value won't be the same as the next.

For example, what I want to avoid:

```
Wrong!
Wrong!
```

Though this is still fine:

```
Wrong!
Incorrect!
Wrong!
```

My code:

```
import random

def wrong():
    wrong_stats=["\n Wrong!","\n Tough Luck!","\n Better Luck Next Time!","\n Not there yet!","\n Incorrect!"]
    rand = random.choice(wrong_stats)
    rand3 = random.choice(wrong_stats)
    norep(rand,rand3,wrong_stats)

def norep(rand,rand3,wrong_stats):
    if rand == rand3:
        same = True
        while same:
            rand = random.choice(wrong_stats)
            if rand != rand3:
                print(rand)
                break
            
    elif rand != rand3:
        print(rand)

wrong()
wrong()
wrong()
wrong()
wrong()
```

Comment: You choose what to print, and then when you call `wrong()` again you forget what you just chose and you never check that your new choice is different from the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to keep track of the last value it returned; you could

- use a module global for this *(usually messy in practice)*,
- or turn it into a class *(kind of verbose)*,
- or keep track externally and pass it in each time *(clunky and tedious)*,

but imo the nicest way to do it would be to turn your `wrong` function into a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) instead: that way you can keep track of the last returned value in the generator execution state, and avoid it next time around, without having to worry about that in external code anywhere.

```
def wrong():
    wrong_stats = ["Wrong!","Tough Luck!","Better Luck Next Time!","Not there yet!","Incorrect!"]
    previous_value = None
    while True:
        value = random.choice(wrong_stats)
        if value != previous_value:
            yield value
            previous_value = value
```

And usage:

```
w = wrong()
for i in range(5):
    print(next(w))

# Tough Luck!
# Incorrect!
# Not there yet!
# Tough Luck!
# Better Luck Next Time!
```

You can keep calling `next` with your generator and it will produce an infinite number of strings without ever repeating the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

Global variables are a bad practice.

You should pass the value you printed last to `wrong` and then choose between all the values except that value. Like this:

```
import random

def wrong(last):
    chosen = random.choice([stat for stat in WRONG_STATS if stat != last])
    print(chosen)
    return chosen

if "__main__" == __name__:
    last = None
    for i in xrange(5):
        last = wrong(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the previous value in a global variable, and choose randomly from the list (excluding the previous value):

```
import random

wrong_stats=["\n Wrong!","\n Tough Luck!","\n Better Luck Next Time!","\n Not there yet!","\n Incorrect!"]
prev = ""

def wrong():
  global prev
  if prev == "":
    prev = random.choice(wrong_stats)
  else:
    prev = random.choice(wrong_stats[:wrong_stats.index(prev)] + wrong_stats[wrong_stats.index(prev)+1:])
  print prev
if __name__ == "__main__":
  wrong()
  wrong()
  wrong()
  wrong()
  wrong()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use random.shuffle:

```
from random import shuffle
>>> shuffle(wrong_stats)
>>> wrong_stats
['\n Better Luck Next Time!', '\n Wrong!', '\n Incorrect!', '\n Tough Luck!', '\n Not there yet!']
>>> shuffle(wrong_stats)
>>> wrong_stats
['\n Incorrect!', '\n Tough Luck!', '\n Better Luck Next Time!', '\n Not there yet!', '\n Wrong!']
>>> shuffle(wrong_stats)
>>> wrong_stats
['\n Incorrect!', '\n Wrong!', '\n Better Luck Next Time!', '\n Not there yet!', '\n Tough Luck!']
>>> shuffle(wrong_stats)
>>> wrong_stats
['\n Wrong!', '\n Incorrect!', '\n Better Luck Next Time!', '\n Tough Luck!', '\n Not there yet!']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example that might give you an idea:

```
import random 

country = ["Spain", "Sweden", "Netherlands", "Germany"]
lastcountry = ''
i = 0
while i <= 5:
    country = (random.choice(country))
    if (country != lastcountry):
        i = i + 1
        print (country)
    lastcountry = country
```

It remembers the last option that was picked. 
And if it makes a new selection, it looks if it was not the same as the previeus selection.