# Generating random item in list

Tags: python

How do I adjust this function so if it is run multiple times it does not return the previous direction? For example, if it generated `N`, the next time it would not return `N`.

```
import random
def random_direct():
    directions=['N','S','E','W']
    return random.choice(directions)
```

Thanks for your time!

This question asks to return the random item not print it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805042/python-avoid-previous-value-from-random-selection-from-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python | Avoid previous value from random selection from list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805042/python-avoid-previous-value-from-random-selection-from-list)

Answer (score 3):

```
import random

def random_direct(prev_direction=None):
    directions = [direction for direction in ('N','S','E','W')
                            if direction != prev_direction]
    return random.choice(directions)
```

Comment: `random.choice` won't work with generator, generators have no length. You should use list instead. (Fixed in the answer now)

Comment: Ah, my bad. Classic "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Thanks @avysk!

Answer (score 1):

If you can pass previous direction as in another answer, it's the best. If you cannot, you can do some hackery (I do **not** recommend it):

```
def random_direct(_prev = [None]):
    directions = [direction for direction in ('N', 'S', 'E', 'W')
                            if direction != _prev[0]]
    res = random.choice(directions)
    _prev[0] = res
    return res
```

Call the function without any parameters, like `random_direct()`.