# Python while loop, print one item from array without it being printed twice in a row

Tags: python, random, pyautogui

I want pyautogui to type days in a month from 1 to 31. Bellow each number I want it to type city name from an array. Problem is that when loop finishes, in the next run it has a chance to print the same city which I don't want. It can and should print it again just not twice in a row.

I tried several options I was able to Google but none worked. Here's my code. If you have suggestions on how to fix it or completely new code please let me know.

```
import pyautogui, random

dayDate = 1
while dayDate < 32:
    pyautogui.click(380, 325)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(dayDate))
    pyautogui.click(380, 345)
    cities = ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Barcelona', 'Moscow']
    city = random.choice(cities)
    print(city)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(city))
    dayDate += 1
```

Just that I'm clear, preferable output in terminal should not have same city twice in a row.

Eg:

1. London 2. Berlin 3. Berlin 4. Moscow - wrong
2. Berlin 2. London 3. Berlin 4. Moscow - correct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python | Avoid previous value from random selection from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805042/python-avoid-previous-value-from-random-selection-from-list)

Comment: There is no need to initialize `cities` over and over inside the while loop. Move it to outside. Check my answer.

Comment: @iScripters it looks like something I'm looking for, I will save it somewhere just in case but in this scenario accdias code does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to be like this:

```py
import pyautogui, random

cities = ('London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Barcelona', 'Moscow')
last_city = city = random.choice(cities)

for day in range(1, 32):
    pyautogui.click(380, 325)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(day))
    pyautogui.click(380, 345)
    pyautogui.typewrite(city)
    print(day, city)
    while city == last_city:
        city = random.choice(cities)
    last_city = city
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I want. I'm still new to python (and somewhat still newish to coding in general).
I thought that variables don't keep their values when looping from top again.

Comment: @RUSHWAYC, No worries. I'm glad it helped. If possible, mark my answer as accepted. That will help others with the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Something you could do is store the previous city as a variable. Then, have a while loop where you do a random choice of cities while the city chosen  equals the previous city chosen.

```
import pyautogui, random

dayDate = 1
prevCity = ''
while dayDate < 32:
    pyautogui.click(380, 325)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(dayDate))
    pyautogui.click(380, 345)
    cities = ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Barcelona', 'Moscow']
    city = random.choice(cities)
    while prevCity == city:
        city = random.choice(cities)
    prevCity = city
    print(city)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(city))
    dayDate += 1
```

Comment: There is no need to initialize `cities` over and over inside the while loop. Move it outside.

Comment: I was trying to keep the code as similar to the given code as possible for clarity. So I didn't try to optimize. However, I agree that cities should be moved outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure I understood the problem. Maybe the solution is just remember last printed city and choose a different one?

```
import pyautogui, random

cities = ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Barcelona', 'Moscow']
dayDate = 1
city = prev_city = ""
while dayDate < 32:
    pyautogui.click(380, 325)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(dayDate))
    pyautogui.click(380, 345)
    while city == prev_city:
        city = random.choice(cities)
    prev_city = city
    print(city)
    pyautogui.typewrite(str(city))
    dayDate += 1
```